# Implementing v-for with dynamic element in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to build a small application in `Vuejs 2.4` where I'm having some data defined as:

```
data() {
    return {
        backLogs: '',
        open: '',
        inProgress: '',
        done: '',
        accepted: '',
        sent: '',
    }
},
```

I'm having different `axios` calls which gives the value of these data points so I mentioned those in `beforeCreate()` function like this:

```
beforeCreate() {
    axios.get('api/to-do/back-logs', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            this.backLogs = response.data.tasks
        }
    })
    axios.get('api/to-do/open', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            this.open = response.data.tasks
        }
    })
    axios.get('api/to-do/in-progress', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            this.inProgress = response.data.tasks
        }
    })
    axios.get('api/to-do/done', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            this.done = response.data.tasks
        }
    })
    axios.get('api/to-do/accepted', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            this.accepted = response.data.tasks
        }
    })
    axios.get('api/to-do/sent', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            this.sent = response.data.tasks
        }
    })
},
```

Now to display the list in my `HTML` i.e. `template` part I'm having:

```
<div class="nits-agile-task">
    <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h3>Back Logs</h3>
            <p class="small"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i> Drag task between list</p>
            <draggable :options="{group: 'task-list'}" :element="'ul'" class="sortable-list connectList agile-list" @change="update">
                <li v-for="item in backLogs" :class="color(item.priority)">
                    <router-link :to="{path: '/task/'+item.unique_id}">
                        <strong>{{ item.title }}.</strong>
                    </router-link>
                    <div v-if="item.project" class="agile-detail">
                        Project name: <router-link :to="{path: '/project/'+item.project.unique_id}">{{ item.project.title }}</router-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="agile-detail">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ item.created_at }}
                    </div>
                </li>
            </draggable>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This `HTML` template is same for `backLogs, open, inProgress, done, accepted, sent` to keep my code `DRY` (Don't Repeat Yourself) I tried making a variable set:

```
types: [
    {name: 'Back Logs', slug: 'backLogs'},
    {name: 'Open', slug: 'open'},
    {name: 'In Progress', slug: 'inProgress'},
    {name: 'Done', slug: 'done'},
    {name: 'Accepted', slug: 'accepted'},
    {name: 'Sent', slug: 'sent'}
]
```

Then I simply added `v-for` with this `types` so now my template looks like:

```
<div v-for="type in types" class="nits-agile-task">
    <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h3>{{ type.name }}</h3>
            <p class="small"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i> Drag task between list</p>
            <draggable :options="{group: 'task-list'}" :element="'ul'" class="sortable-list connectList agile-list" @change="update">
                <li v-for="item in type.slug" :class="color(item.priority)">
                    <router-link :to="{path: '/task/'+item.unique_id}">
                        <strong>{{ item.title }}.</strong>
                    </router-link>
                    <div v-if="item.project" class="agile-detail">
                        Project name: <router-link :to="{path: '/project/'+item.project.unique_id}">{{ item.project.title }}</router-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="agile-detail">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ item.created_at }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="agile-detail">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-white">Feature</a>
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-white">Fixes</a>
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-white">To Do</a>
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-white">Bugs</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </draggable>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it is giving me absurd results:

[image]

But when I see the console there are only 3 elements in each data point.

[image: Vue Console]

Hope you get what I'm trying to achieve, help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: For me this code a little bit confusing: v-for="item in type.slug"
You use v-for on types, and trying v-for on type.slug, in this case you can translate v-for="item in type.slug" as item in 'backLogs'. v-for on string... how it may works?)

Comment: @VladislavGritsenko yes I understood the problem, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Don't initialise data in the `beforeCreate` hook, data observation has not been set up at that point, instead, initilisation should be done in the `created` hook. It also looks like you should break your panels down in to a single component that accepts a `type` as a prop ('in-progress', 'done' etc) which you can use to fetch and display your data.

Answer (score 0):

If your tasks data looks like associative array, for example:

```js
{
  'backLog': [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: '...'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: '...'
    },
    ...
  ]
  'inProgress': [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: '...'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then you can access tasks array in v-for like this: `v-for="item in tasks[type.slug]"`

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use :

```
v-for="item in $data[type.slug]"
```

Thanks to *thanksd* comment.

Comment: It would need to be `$data[type.slug]`. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data